# Python Logger Debug level not outputting anything

Tags: python, python-logging

I initially creating my python logger set to INFO level, but a requirement changed and I need to set to DEBUG instead. It works fine and outputs logs for INFO but I don't get anything for DEBUG.

```
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG, filename="logging.log", filemode='w', format="%(levelname)s - %(message)s")

logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

handler = logging.StreamHandler()
file_handler = logging.FileHandler('logging.log')

formatter = logging.Formatter("%(asctime)s - %(levelname)s - %(name)s - %(message)s")
file_formatter = logging.Formatter("%(asctime)s - %(levelname)s - %(name)s - %(message)s")

handler.setFormatter(formatter)
file_handler.setFormatter(file_formatter)

logging.getLogger().handlers.clear()
logger.addHandler(handler)
logger.addHandler(file_handler)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    
    logger.debug("App Initiated")
    run_ui()
```

Am I missing something? Anyone run into a similar issue?

Comment: Where are you looking for the log messages? Additionally, the first line in your code has an indentation error. I'm not sure if it was a copy/paste error or if it was intentional.

Comment: Right now just trying to test out very basic messages. The "app initiated" message is logged for INFO, and I can set it for every other kind of message as well. Debug just doesn't work for some reason. And the indentation is just a copy/paste error

Comment: But where is the log messaged being logged to? That's what I mean by where are you looking for the log messages.

Comment: Ahh sorry! I just updated the code here. I pasted the wrong one. I am logging to a file and to console

Comment: I can't reproduce the issue. At least not with the code posted in the question (which, by the way, seems to have a line outside of the code block). I see `"App Initiated"` in both the terminal and in a `logging.log` file. Are you trying to see `DEBUG` log messages in other parts of the code? (namely, other Python modules?)